# Find next occurrence of a substring in Python

Tags: python, regex, xml, string, parsing

I want to get next occurrence of a substring starting and ending with specific signs. Now I have first occurrence. Code:

```
start = 'version='
end = '>'
s = 'text text i version="7.0"> text text version="9.0.1"> text text'
result = s[s.find(start)+len(start):s.find(end)].strip()
print result
```

Result is:
"7.0"

I want to have "9.0.1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re.findall` from the `re` module:

```
re.findall('version="(.*?)"', s)
# ['7.0', '9.0.1']
```

You get a list of versions. Pick and use what you need. As a reference, the second item is accessed with `[1]`.